# Sharing a list between processes in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I have one module that reads data from a shell script in real time, and i want to be able to format and process each line without fail, and output with as minimal latency as possible

I've started looking into multiprocessing and i figured the best way would be to make a shared list and get one process to append to it, and the other (if any elements are in it) to read from it and do the processing

manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
line_queue = manager.list()

```
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
line_queue = manager.list()

def run_command(command, mylist):
    process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:
        output = process.stderr.readline()
        if output == '' and process.poll() is not None:
            break
        if output:
            testline = output.strip().decode("utf-8")
            mylist.append(testline)
    rc = process.poll()
    return rc


cmd = "shell script"
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_command, args=(cmd,line_queue))
p.start()
p.join()
```

However, i can't manage to read from that list until the "p" process terminates, and if i do not use p.join() it throws a:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 619, in SocketClient
    s.connect(address)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```